# Paypal IPN - How does it work?

Tags: php, html, paypal, payment

I need a brief explanation on how Paypal IPN works. Not anything in details just the basic stuff.

How should I set my HTML variables and how should I get the data to verify the payment from Paypal? This is all I need to know and I can't find a quick explanation on this one somewhere.

If possible, show me some code lines too, would definitely help.

Thanks.

Comment: I found very useful (and easy to use) this PHP class: https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks for your comment - if it was an answer I'd definitely accept it :D

Comment: Posted as an answer! Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found very useful (and easy to use) [this PHP class](http://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN):

Answer (score 4):

**[IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)** is a message service that **[PayPal](https://www.paypal.com/)** uses to send notifications about specific events, such as:

- Instant payments, including Express Checkout, direct credit card
  payments and authorizations (transaction payments that are authorized
  but have not yet been collected)
- eCheck payments and associated status, such as pending, completed, or
  denied, and payments pending for other reasons, such as those being
  reviewed for potential fraud
- Recurring payment and subscription actions
- Chargebacks, disputes, reversals, and refunds associated with a
  transaction

In many cases, the action that triggers an IPN event is a user-action on your website. However, other actions can trigger IPNs. For example, your site's back-office process might invoke a PayPal API that refunds a payment, or a customer might notify PayPal of a disputed charge.

You receive and process IPN messages with a listener (sometimes called a handler). This listener is basically a web page or web application that you create on your server that is always active and had code that allows it to accept and verify IPN messages sent from PayPal, and then invoke backend services on your server, based on the information from the IPN message. The web application waits for IPNs and (typically) passes them to an administrative process that responds appropriately. PayPal provides sample code that can be modified to implement a listener that handles the IPN sent from messages PayPal. For details, see Implementing an [**IPN listener**](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNImplementation/).

For detailed information and help please visit: **[PayPal Instant Payment Notification Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/)**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

### Code

I've used the c# equivalent of this many times (and the PHP version looks quite similar).

https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623

```
<?php
  //reading raw POST data from input stream. reading pot data from $_POST may cause serialization issues since POST data may contain arrays
  $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
  $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
  $myPost = array();
  foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval)
  {
      $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
      if (count($keyval) == 2)
         $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
  }
  // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
  $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
  if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc'))
  {
       $get_magic_quotes_exits = true;
  } 
  foreach ($myPost as $key => $value)
  {        
       if($get_magic_quotes_exits == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1)
       { 
            $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value)); 
       }
       else
       {
            $value = urlencode($value);
       }
       $req .= "&$key=$value";
  }

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: www.paypal.com'));
// In wamp like environment where the root authority certificate doesn't comes in the bundle, you need
// to download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path 
// of the certificate as shown below.
// curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, dirname(__FILE__) . '/cacert.pem');
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// assign posted variables to local variables
$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];


if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment
}
else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
}
?>
```

### Overview

Basically, PayPal contacts you and you respond; this allows you to validate that it was PayPal invoking your IPN handler and not a malicious party. After that validation step, you can proceed with processing the results. As I'm sure you know, an IPN call is made after a payment occurs (and also can be configured for other events in the payment lifecycle). You can use IPN to update a system status (e.g. unlocking a purchased product).

### Other Stuff

- The last development URL I used for PayPal was https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr (probably still valid)
- The IPN page/handler needs to be publicly available for PayPal to invoke.
- You'll need to configure IPN notifications in the PayPal developer UI (which mainly involves giving them the URL to your IPN page)
- You can send custom information to PayPal with the original transaction that PayPal will send back to the IPN handler. I believe it is passed in a field called "custom".

Comment: Thanks. I thought Paypal IPN requires some setting up and I never thought I could directly use it like this. I'm testing my code with the Paypal sandbox, does this mean I have to change the `www.` in this code to `sandbox.` ?

Comment: You'll probably need to change the URL...you'll also need to setup test IPN notifications in the developer area. The PayPal configuration UI is confusing but the actual IPN process is straightforward.

Comment: You'll also need to make sure that PayPal can access your IPN handler, i.e. it needs to be a public URL.

Comment: It's public and it's a simple url that looks like this `http://localhost/phpsite/donations/donate/index.php?mode=success`, but when I return from paypal to this page, the ?mode=success get replaced with some **merchant** stuff. :\

Comment: "localhost" probably isn't public...and to be clear, IPN is different from a return URL. It's called behind the scenes by PayPal (usually within a few seconds of a transaction being completed).

Comment: The document that @AlphaMale linked to has good information on the process too: https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf

Comment: Well, I have to try stuff on localhost first before going public, I guess. I also set notify-url to the same url I showed you above, meaning I will receive all IPN information in that url. When I open Paypal's source code just before returning to my localhost, there is a GET form pointing to my exact return url and and the form name attribute is `name="merchant_return"`, and once we get back to my page, nothing is left of my `?mode=success`, meaning I can't verify payment data at all.

Comment: Unfortunately you have to have a public URL for IPN to work correctly, which does make it hard to test. The return URL is different from IPN. If I recall, anyone could fake the return URL and act like they had completed the transaction, but the IPN provides secure validation.

Comment: Maybe Paypal doesn't prefer such urls for `notify-url` and `return` and I can pass that `&mode=success` in a custom hidden field?

Comment: Here's a related link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736598/paypal-return-url. Apparently, PayPal strips out query string parameters but it looks like you can use a custom field.