# Is there any way of return to website after unsubscribe paypal recurring payment

Tags: paypal, returnurl, unsubscribe

Is there any way of return to website after unsubscribe paypal recurring payment.

I am using link button to unsubscribe current recurring payment .

Complete process is working fine except returning to merchant site .

Hope someone will point me in right direction.

Comment: check this 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2736598/paypal-return-url

I hope this will help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just use the "ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus" API to cancel the profile.   The buyer would not even need to be redirected over to PayPal, so you can keep the buyer or person cancelling the profile on your site the entire time.  This eliminates the need to redirect the buyer back to your site.

Comment: Thanks PP. Yes I have used "ManageRecurringPaymentsProfileStatus" and it works perfectly.